# Is it possible to use pipes in OCaml?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

In F# I can't live without pipes (`<|` and `|>`)

```
let console(dashboard : Dashboard ref) = 
    let rec eat (command : string) =
        command.Split(' ','(',')') 
        |> Seq.filter(fun s -> s.Length <> 0)
        |> fun C ->
            (Seq.head C).ToUpper() |> fun head ->
```

Can I use `<|` and `|>` in OCaml?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These are available since OCaml 4.01. However, `<|` is named `@@` there, so it has the correct operator associativity.

Alternatively, you can either define them yourself:

```
let (|>) v f = f v
let (<|) f v = f v  (* or: *)
let (@@) f v = f v
```

Or you use [Ocaml batteries included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/), which has the `|>` and `<|` operators defined in BatStd.

Comment: update: in 4.01.0 `|>` is included in the stdlib, and `@@` is defined the same as `|<`.

Comment: @nlucaroni thanks! I wonder why they chose `@@` instead of something obviously complementary to forward piping? (`<|` seems like the best option to me, but `|<` at least uses analogous glyphs).

Comment: It's because of the associativity necessary in the grammar. `@` is used to start infix functions with right association, while `|` is used for left. This has been the standard for awhile. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150551/ocaml-why-i-cant-use-this-operator-infix

Comment: The answer should be edited to reflect the current state of `|>` and `@@`.

Comment: @vog I haven't followed the recent updates to ocaml for a while. Maybe you could add the updates?