# What does |> do?

Tags: operators, ocaml

From *Real World OCaml*, page 38(see https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variables-and-functions.html#prefix-and-infix-operators). It defines a function:

```
# let (|>) x f = f x ;;
```

and applied it to strings:

```
# let path = "/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin";;
val path : string = "/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin"
#   String.split ~on:':' path
  |> List.dedup ~compare:String.compare
  |> List.iter ~f:print_endline
  ;;
/bin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
- : unit = ()
```

I am wondering - what does the operator do, really? I am confused  because `List.iter` is a function and `print_endline` is a function as well. Reading the code I do not see where `String.compare` or `List.dedup` operates on the given *path* string. I read the book over and over again, it says:

"
It's not quite obvious at first what the purpose of this operator is: it just takes a value and a function and applies the function to the value. Despite that bland-sounding description, it has the useful role of a sequencing operator, similar in spirit to using the pipe character in the UNIX shell. Consider, for example, the following code for printing out the unique elements of your PATH. Note that List.dedup that follows removes duplicates from a list by sorting the list using the provided comparison function. "

But why would the two functions operates on "*path*" after all? Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: The operator is sometimes called a "pipe" - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986010/is-it-possible-to-use-pipes-in-ocaml

Comment: That post only give a construction identical to this one, but I am still lost what is the use of this one.

Comment: I decided to search piping on my own instead. I found some articles but I still feel really confused.

Comment: Yeah, OCaml documentation seems to be sparse on this pattern (just bits here and there) - If you're willing to deal with an F# resource, http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-composition/ is a fairly good read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're looking at the complete definition of this operator. It takes a value (at the left) and a function (at the right) and applies the function to the value. The use of a symbol starting with `|` means that the operator associates to the left. So `a |> b |> c` is equivalent to `(a |> b) |> c`.

It seems you're more confused by higher-order functions than by the `|>` operator. Yes, `List.iter` is a function, but it takes a function as its first argument. So it's no surprise that `print_endline` is a function also. In fact `List.iter ~f: print_endline` is also a function. This function is applied to the value  of the previous part of the expression (a list). This is what `|>` does.

If it helps any, `|>` is intended to be similar to the `|` of the Unix command line. You can specify an initial value and a series of functions to be applied to it like a pipeline.

Comment: Sorry I had no prior exposure to UNIX. I have to read your answer carefully. Thank you!

Comment: Just ignore the part about Unix then, it's just one way of looking at the operator.

Comment: After careful reading, now everything starts to make sense. I have to a question - why we place |> x f in the definition, but in actual practice it "takes a value at the left and a function at the right"? Should not it be that |> takes both the value and the function at the right?

Comment: Well, OCaml uses parentheses to transform an infix operator into a prefix function. So the definition follows that convention. E.g., you can say `(+) 3 4` (try it).

Comment: I see! Now the contents in that section is finally making sense. I cannot thank you enough.