# What does |> mean in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I was reading some source code and came across |>

I tried googling but it is too hard to google symbols.

I am new to Ocaml, can anyone explain? Please and thank you!

Comment: It is the equivalent of the pipe in unix shell, very useful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does |> do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747891/what-does-do)

Answer (score 6):

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#6_Compositionoperators

It is a reverse application operator; the argument goes on the left, the function to apply to the argument on the right.

```
x |> f = f x
```

*Updated reference page: https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#1_Compositionoperators*